Filter sets by a boolean column
I have a list of customers and there are many duplicates. To solve this problem the business is setting one of them as primary. The process has not been followed; I need to find all the customers that don't have a primary key. The customers' legal_name values all match, and the is_primary field is Boolean. How can I do this?
I have sorted and organized the list but can not figure out how to check for each customer if is there a primary set.
select distinct customer_id, 
       COUNT(customer_id) as C, 
       is_primary from customer_table
where  is_primary = false
group by customer_id, is_primary 
order by C ASC


Is COUNT(customer_id)  needed in the final result?

Took your query and altered it using a HAVING clause (see details here)
SELECT
    customer_id, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN is_primary THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as C
from customer_table 
group by customer_id
having COUNT(CASE WHEN is_primary THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 0


In SQL-Server you could do this:
SELECT  customer_id
FROM customer_table
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN is_primary=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) =0

fiddle

Other Solutions and examples https://dbfiddle.uk/3QnRwJgs
